# Leaflet change marker for wpt

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gpx

I have an html page which uses Leaflet, I import the data via a.gpx file. I would like to know if it is possible to modify the markers of the cities which are `<wpt>` tags to have an icon. This is what I currently have :

[image]

EDIT :
@ghybs

> How do you read the .gpx file and create Leaflet Layers from it?

```
        var map = L.map('map');
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.osm.org">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }).addTo(map);

        var gpx = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/resultat.gpx'; 

         new L.GPX(gpxFile, {
            async: true,
            marker_options: {
            wptIconUrls: {
              '': '/Leaflet/marker-icon.png',
             },
            startIconUrl: '/Leaflet/start.png',
            endIconUrl: '/Leaflet/start.png',
            shadowUrl: '/Leaflet/pin-shadow.png'
          }
        }).on('loaded', function (e) {
          let gpx = e.target;
          map.fitBounds(gpx.getBounds());
        }).addTo(map);
```

I edited the code and picture, icons are visible but the start/end icon is under the waypoint icon. I didn't find how to have only `start.png`.

Comment: How do you read the .gpx file and create Leaflet Layers from it?

Comment: @ghybs I edited my post to answer your question.

Comment: Have you tried what is proposed in leaflet-gpx plugin doc for waypoint icons? https://github.com/mpetazzoni/leaflet-gpx/blob/master/README.md#about-waypoints

Comment: @ghybs No, I will try this tomorrow. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @ghybs I almost succeeded, I just have a problem with the icons they overlap. I edited the code, I don't know if I need to make a new post or just edit.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `wptIconUrls: false` and the waypoint icons will not be shown and overlapping.

Comment: While this visually works (and may improve performance), the console could be showing a notice for every waypoint as no icon can be matched. E.g.: `No waypoint icon could be matched for ​…​`​ etc.